# I have an error like "expected ]" in NSDictionary post method data parsing

Tags: objective-c

```
NSDictionary *checkIn = [NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"emp_id" : "your employee id", @"checkin_image" : "", @"checkin_time" : "" ,nil];
```

I have an error in `@"checkin_image"` : after I found it.

Comment: You need another [ at the start `NSDictionary *checkIn = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"emp_id" : "your employee id", @"checkin_image" : "", @"checkin_time" : "" ,nil];`

Comment: again error showing

Comment: I didn't realise you have confused dictionary literal syntax with the method syntax.  It should be `NSDictionary *checkIn = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"emp_id", "your employee id", @"checkin_image" , "", @"checkin_time" , "" ,nil];`

Answer (score 1):

NSDictionary  `initWithObjectsAndKeys:` must have object before key and separated by `,` not `:`

```
NSDictionary *checkIn = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"your employee id", @"emp_id", @"", @"checkin_image", @"", @"checkin_time",  nil];
```

or you declare shorter with NSDictionary literal:

```
NSDictionary *checkIn = @{@"emp_id" : @"your employee id", @"checkin_image" : @"", @"checkin_time" : @""};
```

Answer (score 0):

please add [ at start , if you want to add any value or key which is string then add @ before string and remove : from from code just add , instead of :

Please use like this it will be help you

```
NSDictionary *checkIn = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"emp_id" , @"your employee id", @"checkin_image" , @"", @"checkin_time" , @"" ,nil];
```